# How to find ip number from IIS Server?

Tags: iis, server, ip, port

I want to find ip number of web site. But on IIS's Browse Web Site Section, Adress was Browse*:190 How can I find ip address of the web site.

I write url as http://91.235.104.132:190/ but I got ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT error. http://91.235.104.132 is connected 80 port and add 80 at the link, web site works.

Comment: You need to learn IIS binding first, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to find ip number of web site. But on IIS's Browse Web Site Section, Adress was Browse*:190 How can I find ip address of the web site.

As far as I know, the defualt IP port to access IIS web site is 80. If you want to access the web site with sepcial port, you should add port binding for the web application.

The address is your server's Ip address, so the url may like http://91.235.104.132:190/. If you still couldn't access the web application by using this port, I suggest you could try to check your server's firewall to make sure it allow that port firstly.

Then I suggest you could try to use `netstat -ano` to check if the port is listening or not.

Binding image:

[image]

Comment: I do not have a permission to adjust port on firewall because I am not admin of the server. According to your comment, "allow the port" will solve the problem. For now, I will add a new site below 80 port as a new application. My code has app-url which means we can redirect url at the sam port